# Context.Wait() isn't triggered by an attachment

Tags: c#, botframework

[Update] I verify another thing and it appears that my bot, hosted in Azure, just doesn't accept anymore any kind of attachment...

I just update to the 3.81 version of the Bot Framework and one thing isn't working anymore.

I expect from the user to send either a text or an attachment. So I wait for the response with `context.Wait(waitForAnswer)`

But the method `waitForAnswer` doesn't trigger if the user sends an attachment... Now if I want to receive one, it seems that the only way is using `PromptDialog.Attachment`... but this isn't fine for my use case because I don't know if the user will send an attachment or a simple text message.

Note that within the emulator, the function `waitForAnswer` is correctly triggered by an attachment... But when I try to use Telegram channel or simply the webchat, problem rise

Comment: Can you provide your code ?

Comment: What channel(s) is this not working in?  You said it works in the emulator, where is it not working for you?